# Symfony2 launch functions from form, tags in a post

Tags: php, forms, symfony, service, tags

I have defined a series of functions of a Tag entity (index, create, edit etc.) as a service. When I create a post in the form I add the field "tags" to include the tags related to that post.

My question is, How can I implement the functions I have defined within the TagManager? The function I want to use is called 'newOrLoadTag'. I am not sure how should I use it, if within the PostController, or the PostForm.

My second question is, how can I limit the input tags? I want a post to have a max of 5 tags. I think I should define the field "tags" of the Post entity as an array of size 5. Is it the best way to do it? If it is so, how can I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

you should prohibe adding more than 5 tags on the client (js)-frontend side, personally i would use chosen.js multiple select, or tagsinput.js

your function newOrLoad inside tagservice could look like:

```
public function newOrLoadTag($tagName){
    $foundTag=$tagRepo->findOneByName($tagName);
    if($foundTag){
        return $foundTag;
    }else{
        //should return instance of Tag
        return $this->createTag($tagName)
    }
}
```

inside your PostController you can get the tags from request, lets assume its a string and the chosen tagname are seperated by ";"

```
    if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $post=$form->getData();
            // get tags from request
            $tags=$request->get('tags') ? urldecode($request->get('tags')) : false;

            // persist the post and remove all tags 
            $em->persist($post);
            foreach ($entity->getTags() as $tag) {
                $post->removeTag($tag);
            }
            // add all tags
            if($tags){
                $tags=explode(';', $tags); 
                $c=1;
                foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                    if($c<=5){
                      $tag = $tagService->newOrLoadTag($tag);
                      $post->addTag($tag);  
                    }
                    $c++;
                }   
            }
            //...
```